# ASP.Net Application Idle Timeout and App Pool Recycling

Tags: iis-7, httpwebrequest, webclient, application-pool, hangfire

I have the following job schedlued to run every minute using hangfire to try and keep my site alive but it still seems to idle out? I've just checked the hangfire dashboard and looks like the job never ran over the weekend presumembly because no one visited the site (note it's an intranet application)

```
 try
 {
    var url = "http://xyz.domain.com/myapp"
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Timeout = 6000;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; 
    request.Method = "HEAD";

    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
               // TO DO
    }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     logger.Error(ex, "Error in KeepAlive job");
 }
```

Would using webclient be more reliable or is it the same as using HttpWebRequest -something like below:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead("http://xyz.domain.com/myapp");
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Hangfire Server instance in a web application will not be started until the first user hits your site. Even more, there are some events that will bring your web application down after some time (I’m talking about Idle Timeout and different app pool recycling events). In these cases your recurring tasks and delayed jobs will not be enqueued, and enqueued jobs will not be processed.

This is particulary true for smaller sites, as there may be long periods of user inactivity. But if you are running critical jobs, you should ensure that your Hangfire Server instance is always running to guarantee the in-time background job processing.

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html